# Expression analysis

Tags: r, tm

I use `tm` package to analyse 5 docs. Initially the data is in csv format, contains few columns. I searched for most common words in the 1st column which represents the title of some books.(i created separate txt doc for each needed column).

Now I want to analyse the column that contains the First and Last Name of the authors (eg. John, Smith). I want to determine the number(frequency) of books for each author.

Please tell me how can I analyse both words together not separately like in the first case?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the variable name_author into factor, then you have juste to determine how frequency you have for each levels (Authors).